# Keycloak. Storage SPI with external database

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We already have DB with users.
We have to migrate all records to Keycloak DB or we can just implement Storage SPI ?

We don't want to migrate records, because we should also support old DB, it brings problems because we will need synchronize 2 DB.

Can you please write what could be the problems in this approach and write your advices for resolve theirs ?

Answer (score 0):

**USER DATA SOURCES**

Moving to a system such as Keycloak will require an architectural design on how to manage user fields. Some user fields will need migrating to an identity database managed by Keycloak. Applications can then receive updates to these fields within tokens.

**KEYCLOAK DATA**

Keycloak will expect to have its own user account storage, and this is where each user's `subject claim` will originate from. If a new user signs up, the user will be created here before being created in your business data.

Keycloak user data will include fields such as name and email if they are sent in `forgot password` workflows. You can keep most other user fields in your business data if you prefer.

So to summarize, a migration will be needed, but you don't have to migrate all user fields.

**BUSINESS DATA**

This may include other user fields that you want to keep where they are, but also include in access tokens and use for authorization in APIs. Examples are values like `roles`, `permissions`, `tenant ID`, `partner ID`, `supscription level`.

**DESIGN STEPS**

My [recent blog post](https://thenewstack.io/modern-identity-onboarding-essentials/) walks through some examples and suggests a way to think through your end-to-end flows. There are a couple of different user data scenarios mentioned there.

It is worth doing a day or two of sketching out how you want your system to work. In particular how your APIs will authorize requests, and how you will manage both existing and new users. This avoids the potential for finding expensive problems later.